# Why do some people pronounce "antisemitic" as "antisimetic"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Not a question of grammar but one of pronunciation. I notice many educated Americans mispronounce the word "antisemitic". The word is derived from "semite" which I pronounce to rhyme with "she might" or "Sem might". I hear more often than not a transposition of the vowel sounds which results in "an-ti-sim-et-ic" (with /ɪmɛ/) rather than the correct "an-ti-sem-it-ic" (with /ɛmɪ/). (This pronunciation is listed in the Merriam-Webster entry for ["anti-Semitic"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anti-Semitic).)

That is, the second syllable of *semitic* i.e. SEM is pronounced as though it is written SIM and the third syllable IT is pronounced as though it was written ET. The word is not written SIMETIC but that is the way it is pronounced by some. A Jewish friend of mine also mispronounced the word until I asked him to pronounce it in syllable while looking at the spelling. Why do some of us, I wonder, when we add the prefix *anti-* mess up the pronunciation of the rest of the word?

Comment: @sumelic You're presumably an expert on pronunciation of -ic words. Notable exception: "TUR-me-ric"

Comment: I've also never heard the word pronounced with stress on the 3rd syllable. Since that syllable is unstressed, it's hard to distinguish the precise vowel used.

Comment: I did not refer to the syllable stressed. Allow me to repeat my concern. The second syllable of semitic i.e. SEM is pronounced as though it is written SIM and the third syllable IT is pronounced as though it was written ET. The word is not written SIMETIC but that is the way it is pronounced by some. A Jewish friend of mine also mispronounced the word until I asked him to pronounce it in syllable while looking at the spelling. Why do some of us, I wonder, when we add the prefix "anti" mess up the pronunciation of the rest of the word? This has zilch to do with "ic" words.

Comment: It's the sort of word that different people will sight-read differently.

Comment: Are these the same people who say "nucular"?

Comment: The SEM syllable of *antisemitic* is ***supposed to*** sound like SIM, even if it's spelled differently. Look in [any dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anti-semitic). But why the next syllable is pronounced MET by some people beats me.

Comment: And then there are people who are against arguing about the meanings or definitions of words, who are anti-semantic.

Comment: "Antisemitic" is a word that people read far more often than they hear spoken, and when they hear it spoken they rarely have reason to be confident that it is being pronounced "correctly" (whatever that means).  So most people, recalling only that the word isn't "weirdly" pronounced (all the sounds seem to be there, in approximately the right order), will attempt to "wing it" and use phonetic spelling principles to pronounce it.  But a problem is that the word is a fairly long train of individual consonants separated by "i" or "e" vowels, and the brain does not really have any features to hang

Comment: onto when pronouncing the word.  So most people, rather than pausing to carefully parse the word (if they even have it written down somewhere), will spill out a string alternating consonants and vowels, based partly on memory and partly on spelling.  The alternatives are 1) not use the word at all, 2) pause for an inordinate amount of time to get it correct (consult a dictionary?), 3) simply do the best they can and move on.

Comment: Since it's pronunciation, it may be dialect or from a non-native speaker. Last option might be that they are just illiterate in the sense that don't know how the word is spelt correctly thereby effecting there pronunciation.

Comment: Antisemitism is a nasty, ugly thing. Perhaps some people like to avoid this nasty sounding word so they change it something they think sounds less provocative

Comment: @AledCymro  Diwrnod da! Quite so. You mean like Llanfair PG for for the tongue twister Llanfairpwllgwyngyll (abridged), what?

Comment: "You mean like Llanfair PG for for the tongue twister Llanfairpw" It is not at all "like" or the same. The PG is because most people cannot remember or pronounce "pwllgwyngyllchwirndrobwychllantysiliogogogoch". I hope I got that right. My knowledge of yr hen iaith is somewhat limited. I took the time to memorize it. Diwrmod da i chi a diolch, Peter..

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to hazard a guess that the pronunciation is based on two things: widespread uncertainty as to how *antisemitic* is spelled, and pronunciation conditioning based on similar-sounding words.

---

***Early confusion about how to spell the word 'antisemitic'***

With regard to the first issue, I note that the spelling *antisemetic* is common enough in published (and presumably edited) writings since 1900 to support its own Ngram chart:

[image]

The matches underlying this chart include this one from [*The Advocate: America's Jewish Journal*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YmQ-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA105&dq=%22antisemetic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUl-zdsv_TAhWBKWMKHbs5C4oQ6AEIPjAE#v=onepage&q=%22antisemetic%22&f=false) (September 2, 1922):

> **ANTISEMETIC** MOVEMENT IN GERMANY INCREASING
>
> Berlin (J. T. A.)—In spite of an order issued by the Ministry of Education prohibiting the wearing of **anti-Semetic** designs in schools, the Swastika, which has become the symbol of **anti-Semetism**, is being worn by students, and even teachers in the schools and universities.

Earlier still is this [review of Abraham Cahan, *White Terror and the Red*](https://books.google.com/books?id=urtZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22antisemetic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiupqn1s__TAhVH9mMKHaS3DFoQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22antisemetic%22&f=false), from *Book Review Digest*, volume 1 (1905):

> A story of inner Russia by a member of the Revolutionary party who was forced to flee from Russia to avoid Siberia. The plot concerns the tragic events of a quarter of a century ago, when czar Alexander II. was assassinated by the Nihilists and an **antisemetic** outbreak followed, but it is the Russia of to-day that we see, drawn from a practical knowledge of the subject.

And 24 years before that, we have this instance from the Rev. Dr. Stern, "[The Talmud](https://books.google.com/books?id=lPwAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA79&dq=%22antisemetic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRvczxuP_TAhVO2mMKHR1JBAAQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22antisemetic%22&f=false)," in *Proceedings of the Literary & Philosophical Society of Liverpool* (1881):

> I may well maintain that the whole newly-arrayed **Anti-Semetic** hatred and agitation now going on in Germany can be traced to the following reason: Because the Jews there, as one man, are siding with the party of progress and liberty ; at the same time being dearly attached to the Sovereign and the Royal Family.

And from an undated article in *The Jewish Chronicle*, quoted in "[Letters from Galilee](https://books.google.com/books?id=vmA2AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA525&dq=%22antisemetic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRvczxuP_TAhVO2mMKHR1JBAAQ6AEIWjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22antisemetic%22&f=false)," in *Blackwood's Edinburgh Magazine*, volume 134 (October 1883):

> The return [to Palestine] has formed the aspiration of all the noblest sons of Israel during the Dispersion, and it is not strange that it should still retain its hold on those who inherit their spirit. On the other hand, much is to be said for the opinion that any premature indulgence of this sentiment is likely to be prejudicial in view of **anti-Semetic** accusations of want of patriotism.

The spelling *antisemitic* is (not surprisingly) vastly more common in Google Search results, but the earliest match for that spelling is only very slightly earlier than the first instance of *antisemetic* cited above. From [*Punch, or the London Charivari*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pOdbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA47&dq=%22anti+semitic+movement+brown%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjThs2R3oLUAhXhyVQKHUX5CV4Q6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=%22anti%20semitic%20movement%20brown%22&f=false) (January 29, 1881), page 48:

> THE **ANTI-SEMITIC** MOVEMENT.
>
> *Brown. (M.P. for Bloomsbury).* "What a shame, this persecution of the Jews in Berlin!"
>
> Sir Gorgius Midas (flaming up). "'Shame?' Serve 'em right, I say! They're all very well so long as they're kep' under, them 'Ebrews are ; but just you let 'em get the upper 'and, that's all!—and their hignorance, their hostentation, and the haaies they give themselves knows no bounds!"
>
> *Baron von Meyer (who flatters himself, on the strength of his prsonal appearance that no one can suspect his origin).* "Hear! hear! Sir Gorchus! You neffer shboke a druer vort zan zat!"

Joseph Jacobs, writing in [*Trübner's American, European, & Oriental Literary Record*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lIcoAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA101&dq=%22anti+semitic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir8rPV04LUAhXKzVQKHY44B3Q4ChDoAQgsMAI#v=onepage&q=%22anti%20semitic%22&f=false) (1883–1885) conveniently lists various contemporaneous discussion on the Jewish Question as being "Anti-Semitic," "Pro-Semitic," or "Conversionist."

Another interesting instance comes from [*The Catholic World*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5ApGAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA741&dq=%22antisemitic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwmO2jtf_TAhVB2mMKHV0LA-oQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22antisemitic%22&f=false) (March 1889):

> THE **ANTISEMITIC** MOVEMENT IN EUROPE
>
> The **Antisemitic** movement, though hardly ten years old under that name, has thrown a mass of publications on the market among the authors of which we encounter the learned Catholic priest, the professor of theology, the lawyer, the atheist, men of all creeds and no creeds, and hence also a correspondingly great disparity of opinions to the intrinsic merits of the whole question.

---

***English words with '-etic' or '-itic/-ytic' endings***

With regard to the second issue, consider the number of (more or less) common *-etic* words in English:

> *alphabetic*, *aesthetic*, *anesthetic*, *apologetic*, *apathetic*, *arithmetic* (as an adjective), *ascetic*, *athletic*, *bathetic*, *copacetic*, *cosmetic*, *diabetic*, *diarrhetic*, *dietetic*, *diuretic*, *emetic*, *empathetic*, *energetic*, *esthetic*, *exegetic*, *frenetic*, *genetic*, *geodetic*, *hermetic*, *homiletic*, *kinetic*, *magnetic*, *onomatopoetic*, *peripatetic*, *parenthetic*, *pathetic*, *poetic*, *phonetic*, *prophetic*, *prosthetic*, *pyretic*, *splenetic*, *sympathetic*, *synergetic*, *synthetic*, *theoretic*

versus the number of *-itic/-ytic* words:

> *analytic*, *arthritic*, *chondritic*, *critic*, *diacritic*, *electrolytic*, *granitic*, *hemolytic*, *hermaphroditic*, *mephitic*, *nephritic*, *paralytic*, *parasitic*, *psychoanalytic*, *sybaritic*, *syphilitic*

All in all, for people learning the word by hearing (not reading) it, I think it is likelier that they will assign it to the *-etic* class of words than to the *-itic* class of words, the former being considerably more frequently used and heard in English.

---

***Conclusion***

I get the impression that a sizable number of people have been pronouncing (and spelling) *antisemitic* as if it were actually spelled *antisemetic* ever since the term came into English.

In one respect, this is rather odd, given that the spelling *antisemete* is practically unknown to Google Books as an alternative to *antisemite*. But when people try to pronounce a word they are unfamiliar with, they may adapt it to a pronunciation pattern that they are already familiar with, without making much of an effort to connect it to etymologically related words (such as *Semite*) that they may have heard used in other contexts.

Regardless of how the pronunciation "antisemetic" first caught on, it is backed to some degree by the spelling *antisemetic*—which has appeared in published English for more than 130 years.

Comment: It seems unusual to have /ɪ/ in a stressed syllable in a long word, particularly in this position. You come up with some words with stressed /ɪ/ although these tend to either be bisyllabic with stress on the first syllable like critic or to divide nicely into two halves like analytic, with stress on the first syllable of the second half. So I think the combination of stress and sound is definitely unusual and probably awkward or confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think exposure to misspellings of "antisemitic" or rapid speech are enough to explain this widespread phenomenon.  I think it is probably because people are used to hearing "antisemitism", and so they tend to carry over the stressed E sound of that word to the adjectival form without noticing that the stress has shifted to another syllable. The unstressed 4th syllable of "antisemitism" is not pronounced as an I but rather as a shwa, so people are just transposing the E sound and the shwa when they say the adjectival form.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a combination of pronouncing it the way one thinks it is spelled, and many probably have trouble with the spelling of anti-semitic, and fast speech, where the sounds are slurred (February often has the first "r" hidden).  The classic was the JFK library, where we all yelled at the TV, because people kept calling it "liberry".

Comment: Correct. Pronunciation is learned from hearing. We seem to be in a post-literate culture with fewer readers than earlier. Could it be that antisemitism is such a horror. Recently a woman told me I must NOT use the word  "Negro". She thought it was an insult.

Answer (score 0):

Shem, Ham, and Japheth were the three sons of Noah from whom the races of the world, we are told, originate. As a presumed descendant of Japheth, I hope that Shem his brother will not become Shim. I pronounce the word first syllable of "Semitic" to rhyme with "when"; I don't think that is wrong though others may.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have a theory other than people hear it rather than see it. Like saying wah-lah instead of vwah-lah for “voila.” Sorry, I can’t add the diacritic. Both are annoying.  Not related, but other annoying items: vice versa, with the first word only having one syllable, and the abbreviation vs being pronounced as the word verse.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/415710)